# Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

i am new to ubuntu..
I had ubuntu 14.04 installed and today i want to upgrade it to ubuntu 14.10.

Is it safe to upgrade?
P.S. I have faced many problems during past days on ubuntu upgrades :(

Comment: i can't install fresh copy because.. i have many stuffs installed.. and don wanna reinstall it again.. my internet connection is too slow :(

Comment: "Is it safe?" - Well it **should** be, but things can happen, so this question is not really answerable.

Comment: i didn't get an answer anyhow :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the usual " do-release-upgrade " - [checkout this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)  for the many ways to upgrade ubuntu.

Upgrading using the command line:

Run do-release-upgrade in a terminal

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If fails edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`:

```
nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Then run again the above command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: That reply was the most useful for me, could only use the shell and was stuck updating from lts to normal release.

Answer (score 0):

-Open the `Dash`

-Type `Software` in the search field

-Click `Software & Updates`

-Select the 3rd Tab called `Updates`

-Select For any new version from the `Notify me` of a new Ubuntu version drop-down

-Close the `Software & Updates` tool

-Open the Dash

-Type `update-manager`

-When the `Update Manager` opens, it should inform you that a new release is available

-Click `Upgrade`

-Follow the on-screen instructions

I hope this helped